# Backpropagtion with ReLU - Understanding the calculation

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation, relu

I've been getting started with neural networks and am attempting to implement a forward and backward pass with a ReLU activation function. However I feel like I'm misunderstanding something relatively fundamental here when it comes to the backward pass.

```
import numpy as np

class ReLU:
    def __init__(self):
        self.input_tensor = None

    def forward(self, input_tensor):
        self.input_tensor = input_tensor
        return np.maximum(0, input_tensor)

    def backward(self, error_tensor):
        deriv = np.greater(error_tensor, 0).astype(int)

        return self.input_tensor - deriv
```

My question is simple: How is the output of the backward method even supposed to look? My confusion stems from the fact that the derivative of ReLU is simple enough, but I'm not sure how this then is factored into the output that is passed onto the next lecture. I'm absolutely aware that I can't simply subtract the derivative form the old input but I'm unable to see how they go together.

Answer (score 1):

For x > 0 relu is like multiplying x by 1. Else it's like multiplying x by 0. The derivative is then either 1 (x>0) or 0 (x<=0).

So depending on what the output was, you must times the `error_tensor` by 1 or 0.

If it isn't clear, that means you have to save the output of the forward pass to help calculate the gradient.